# The referenced component 'Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android' could not be found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to implement the Notifications for android

I am following [Get started with Notification Hubs with Xamarin for Android](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm/)

and before I reach the end I am getting this error as I noticed that `using WindowsAzure.Messaging;` was giving me the error.

So I tried to look for WindowsAzure.Messaging in NuGet Packages which I could not install

Now I am stuck with my implementation for Notification.

Some Help!

Comment: You said you cannot install the **WindowsAzure.Messaging** component. Do you get an error when you try or what is keeping you from installing it? Also, have you already installed the **Google Cloud Messaging Client Component**?

Comment: Install the from the Azure Messaging component [Xamarin Component Store](https://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-messaging)

Comment: I do have GCM client component already. And when I try to install Windows azure.messaging  I get an error saying not compatible with monidroid something. Moreover when I have azure messaging component installed I get (incomplete ) in from of it. Which requires xamarin.azure.notificationhubs.android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Azure Messaging 1.2.5.0 has some issues. Try to use the previous version - [1.1.5.6](https://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-messaging?version=1.1.5.6). Also try to use Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm version [25.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm/25.0.0) along with Azure Messaging 1.1.5.6.

Comment: It is working just fine now! I take it as if something is not working I need to roll back to previous version after seeing couple of such issues here on VS.